# Check Component Dependency Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, extensions, dependency

I am getting Check Component Dependency in magento 2.3.4 while installing Extension. Please help me to resolve it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that need to be confirmed or may require some changes:

1. First of all, make sure that your server has 2GB or more than 2GB RAM.
2. You will need to edit the php.ini file and set the memory_limit as 2048M.
3. Open .htaccess file on the root directory of your Magento 2 and set memory_limit as 2048M under both mod_php5 and mod_php7 tags.
4. Open .user.ini file on the root directory of your Magento 2 and set memory_limit as 2048M.
5. If you are using PHP-FPM, make sure to set the php_admin_value[memory_limit] as 2048M.
   Make all changes and rerun the Readiness Check.

**Note: If you think the problem is not solved yet and the update doesn't get done. It stays like this:**

[image]

Then let me tell you that this happened with me twice that the console log didn't show anything. After a couple of minutes, maybe 30 to 40 mins, I refreshed the Magento 2 admin panel page and found that the extension was installed successfully.